# Does the usage of header only libraries with different versions result in UB

Tags: c++, static-libraries, static-linking

Lets assume I have a library `somelib.a`, that is distributed as binary by the package manager. And this library makes use of the header only library `anotherlib.hpp`.

If I now link my program against `somelib.a`, and also use `anotherlib.hpp` but with a different version, then this can result in UB, if `somelib.a` uses parts of the `anotherlib.hpp` in its `include` headers.

But what will happen if `somelib.a` will reference/use `anotherlib.hpp` only in its cpp files (so I don't know that it uses them)? Will the linking step between my application and `somelib.a` ensure that `somelib.a` and my application will both use their own version of `anotherlib.hpp`.

The reason I ask is if I link the individual compilation units of my program to the final program, then the linker removes duplicate symbols (depending on if it is internal linkage or not). So a header only library is normally written in a way that removing duplicate symbols can be done.

**A minimal example**

`somelib.a` is build on a system with nlohmann/json.hpp version 3.2

**somelib/somelib.h**

```
namespace somelib {
  struct config {
    // some members
  };

  config read_configuration(const std::string &path);
}
```

**somelib.cpp**

```
#include <nlohmann/json.hpp>


namespace somelib {
  config read_configuration(const std::string &path)
  {
     nlohmann::json j;
     std::ifstream i(path);

     i >> j;

     config c;

     // populate c based on j

     return c;
  }
}
```

application is build on another system with nlohmann/json.hpp version 3.5 and 3.2 and 3.5 are not compatible, and then application is then linked against the `somelib.a` that was build on the system with version 3.2

**application.cpp**

```
#include <somelib/somelib.h>
#include <nlohmann/json.hpp>
#include <ifstream>

int main() {
   auto c = somelib::read_configuration("config.json");

   nlohmann::json j;
   std::ifstream i("another.json");

   i >> j;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: It depends on the library and the compiler, if the library versions are incompatible then yes it wont work. Provide a [mcve]

Comment: @AlanBirtles yes it is about potential incompatible library version. I updated the question to contain a something like a mcve, at least if should hopefully illustrate more clearly  what I'm asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It hardly makes any difference that you are using a static library.

The C++ standard states that if **in a program** there is multiple definitions of an inline function (or class template, or variable, etc.) and all the definitions are not the same, then you have UB.

Practically, it means that unless the changes between the 2 versions of the header library are very limited you will have UB.
For instance, if the only changes are whitespace changes, comments, or adding new symbols, then you will not have undefined behavior. However, if a single line of code in an existing function was changed, then it is UB.

From the [C++17 final working draft (n4659.pdf)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf):

> ### 6.2 One-definition rule
>
> [...]
>
> There can be more than one definition of a class type (Clause 12),
>   enumeration type (10.2), inline function with external linkage
>   (10.1.6), inline variable with external linkage (10.1.6), class
>   template (Clause 17), non-static function template (17.5.6), static
>   data member of a class template (17.5.1.3), member function of a class
>   template (17.5.1.1), or template specialization for which some
>   template parameters are not specified in a program provided that each definition appears in a different translation unit, and provided the definitions satisfy the
>   following requirements.
>
> Given such an entity named D defined in more than one translation
>   unit, then
>
> - each definition of D shall consist of the same
>     sequence of tokens; and
> - in each definition of D, corresponding
>     names, looked up according to 6.4, shall refer to an entity defined
>     within the definition of D, or shall refer to the same entity, after
>     overload resolution (16.3) and after matching of partial template
>     specialization (17.8.3), except that a name can refer to (6.2.1)
>
>   - a non-volatile const object with internal or no linkage if the object
>
>     - has the same literal type in all definitions of D,
>         (6.2.1.2)
>     - is initialized with a constant expression (8.20),
>     - is not odr-used in any definition of D, and
>     - has the same value in all definitions of D,
>
>   or
>
>   - a reference with internal or no linkage initialized with a constant expression
>       such that the reference refers to the same entity in all definitions
>       of D; and (6.3)
> - in each definition of D, corresponding entities
>     shall have the same language linkage; and
> - in each definition
>     of D, the overloaded operators referred to, the implicit calls to
>     conversion functions, constructors, operator new functions and
>     operator delete functions, shall refer to the same function, or to a
>     function defined within the definition of D; and
> - in each definition of
>     D, a default argument used by an (implicit or explicit) function call
>     is treated as if its token sequence were present in the definition of
>     D; that is, the default argument is subject to the requirements
>     described in this paragraph (and, if the default argument has
>     subexpressions with default arguments, this requirement applies
>     recursively).28
> - if D is a class with an implicitly-declared
>     constructor (15.1), it is as if the constructor was implicitly defined
>     in every translation unit where it is odr-used, and the implicit
>     definition in every translation unit shall call the same constructor
>     for a subobject of D.
>
> If D is a template and is defined in more than one translation unit,
>   then the preceding requirements shall apply both to names from the
>   template’s enclosing scope used in the template definition (17.6.3),
>   and also to dependent names at the point of instantiation (17.6.2). If
>   the definitions of D satisfy all these requirements, then the behavior
>   is as if there were a single definition of D. **If the definitions of D
>   do not satisfy these requirements, then the behavior is undefined.**

Comment: So if a library is distributed as static library, then it has to document all libraries (including the header only ones that are only used internally)  with their versions so that the user of that library won't run in such a pitfall. And if I use a static library I should check the symbols myself or switch to a dynamic linked library?

Comment: @t.niese I am not sure that distributing static libraries is good practice. Static libraries are just packaged .o files

Comment: @t.niese The question of documenting which library is used by another library can also affect dynamic libraries, in particular if the shared library is used in the API of the other library. But this is another topic.

Comment: With that information I also think that using a static library from a package manager isn't a good idea, except if the library vendor guarantees ABI compatibility. And that static linking a library should only be done if I created that static library with the sames setup with which I create the application in which I use that static library. Thanks for these information. I already had the suspicion when asking the question, but I'm glad to know that this is indeed the case.